# How to display list of items in the list using iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

here is my JSP code.

```
<h3>All Records:</h3>

<s:iterator value="mainlist">
  <fieldset>
    <s:form action="test.action" method="GET">
      <s:property value="questions"/><br/>
      <s:checkboxlist list="list" name="op1"/>
      <s:property value="answer"/><br/>
      <s:submit value="end exam"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
  </fieldset>
</s:iterator>
```

here `mainlist` contains 2 questions with 4 options each. those 4 options are there is 'list'. I am trying to display those questions with options on web page. but nothing is displayed on the page, except 'All Records:'. what is the problem with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done using Iterator

```
<s:iterator value="list" >          
<s:property value="columnName"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="variable" items='${requestScope.attributeName}'>
       <c:out value="${variable.attr}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: forEach is not there in <s:/> tag

Comment: are you using suggestion by pressing ctrl+space while coding if you are using old ide it will not display

Comment: c:forEach is not a Struts Tag, it is JSTL